# How do I export Whitewater as VDB from Houdini to use in another program?

Tags: simulation, blender, houdini, openvdb

I've had great success exporting fire and smoke as VDB to then open in another 3D program, but I keep failing at exporting whitewater as VDB which can successfully be opened in the next program. It imports with the right attributes and dimensions, but nothing is visible within the object, just the boundary box.

I can't seem to find straightforward documentation on how to do it. My steps are to go into "whitewater_import" add a filecache node to the "render" null and save it to the frame range to disk with the proper naming convention.

I'm using Blenders experimental branch New Object Types. But again, I've had no problem with Fire and Smoke sims in this workflow, I think I'm just doing the process wrong for the whitewater.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you convert the whitewater particles to VDB before exporting ?

Comment: No. Oh my god that was dumb. Thank you so much!!!!